# Node.js express add default value mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, api

So I have nodejs api with post method. I got error query because I don't input data on total_post.

This is my code:

```
var db = require('./../db');
module.exports.jumlah=function(req,res){

    var data={

        "id_account":req.body.id_account,
        "name":req.body.name,
        "address":req.body.address,
        "total_post":req.body.total_post
    }
    console.log(data);

    db.query('INSERT INTO t_jumlah SET ?',data, function (error, results, fields) {
      if (error) {
        res.json({
            status:false,
            message:'there are some error with query'
        })
      }else{
          res.json({
            status:true,

            message:'data inserted sucessfully'
        })
      }
    });
}
```

I want if I don't input data on field total_post, it's automatically input 0 value. How do I make it happen?

Comment: try using `"total_post":req.body.total_post || 0`

Comment: @akshaygore it's work. thnks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this?

```
"total_post":req.body.total_post || 0
```

If total_post is undefined or false, it would fall back to 0